# Node - Express - Recursive Route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node / Express app. In this app, I have the following routes setup:

```
app.use('/article/:title/demo', function(req, res) {
  console.log('load the demo view');
  res.render('article/demo', { title: req.params.title }); 
});    

app.use('/article/:title', function(req, res) {
  console.log('view the article');
  res.render('article/content', { title: req.params.title });
});
```

My article/content file loads fine. However, my article/demo causes a recursive load. I do not understand why. My /article/demo.html file looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <article>
<iframe style="width:100%; height:800px; overflow-y:scroll;" src="./demo/main.html"></iframe>
    </article>    
</body>
</html>
```

I have a main.html file that exists. However, it's not getting rendered. When I look at the console window, I notice that 

`load the demo view`

is begin printed repeatedly as long as I leave the browser window open. I can actually see the article/demo file get loaded within itself. However, I never see the contents of main.html. I'm not sure how to remedy this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your demo.html page rendering properly ?

Comment: Are you using ant template engine like jade or ejs ? @user687554

Comment: @Sumseet - Yes. Demo.html is rendering correctly. It contains an iframe. It's the url referenced in the iframe that's not rendering correctly.

Comment: @Sumeet - I'm using ejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View is rendering your file correctly , but not able to access main.html as it is not available in static folder . Relative path loading will not work , you need to have static folder something like below . Place your file inside that .

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));// Load static files`

Answer (score 0):

Your `/article/:title/demo` is being matched when the browser asks the server for `./demo/main.html`. That is probably not the right path for main.html. This heavily depends on how you've set up your static asset loading.

Comment: I understand that. However, how do I setup a route so that static files in that route can be loaded?

Comment: Don't use relative paths (remove the dot from `./demo/main.html`). Use absolute paths e.g. /demo/main.html and configure express to load files from the folder that your static file are located http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html